PubSub testing issue on GCP
I have created a topic under Pub/Sub service of GCP and then I created two subscribers under that topic out of which one is of "Pull" delivery type and the other one is of "Write to BigQuery" delivery type.
Then I want to test if my subscriptions can receive a manually published message from the console only. So it consists of two steps:
Step 1 : Manually publish a message containing data and attributes with metadata to this topic
Step 2 : Select a Cloud Pub/Sub subscription to pull messages from
I have two questions here:
Q1. Why am I not able to see my "Write to BigQuery" delivery type subscription for the above mentioned step 2 to select a subscription from the drop down?
Q2. Is there some other way (apart from Dataflow pipeline) on GCP console to test my "Write to BigQuery" delivery type subscription?
I already tried to create different configuration of topics with subscriptions but nothing worked.

Hi , could you please share the error message you are getting and some more clarification on the  issue .
